# Is it possible to use bnd with maven-bundle-plugin to produce eclipse feature?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, bnd, bndtools

I am using maven-bundle-plugin to generate plugins for Eclipse. Now I need to generate Eclipse feature. How can I achieve it ?

I do not want to use PDE for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [Tycho](https://eclipse.org/tycho/) to do maven-based builds of Eclipse-based projects. It inherently knows about Eclipse concepts like bundles, plugins, features, and products, so you don't have to try to hack maven into dealing with those things.